# How to add a key value pair into a JSON file with JQ?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON file located at `/tmp/target.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to add a new key value pair so it will be as follows:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    ...
  }
}
```

I use the following command but it doesn't work:

```
jq --argjson addobj '{"skipLibCheck": "true"}' '
  .compilerOptions{} |= $addobj
' /tmp/target.json
```

I gives me this error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 2:
  .compilerOptions{} |= $addobj                  
jq: 1 compile error
```

What have I done wrong?  How can I get it to work as intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to add the key with its value has been covered [in another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735762/116858). That answer adds the key to the end of the list of keys in the `compilerOptions` object. Normally, the ordering of the keys does not matter, and if you need things ordered in a particular way, you will use an *array*. However, I'm noticing that you (for whatever reason) expect the key to be added first, before the existing `baseUrl` key.

We can add the key in that position by, instead of adding the new key to the existing object, instead, add the existing object's keys to the end of the new key. So given the existing JSON document,

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "jerry": "Was a race car driver"
  }
}
```

... we may want to use

```bash
jq --argjson skipLibCheck true '.compilerOptions = $ARGS.named + .compilerOptions' file
```

Given our example document above, this would generate

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "jerry": "Was a race car driver"
  }
}
```

The `$ARGS.named` thing is an object which contains the key-value pairs defined with `--arg` and/or `--argjson` on the command line. In the example above, this would be `{"skipLibCheck":true}`. Note that the `$ARGS` feature was introduced after release 1.5 of `jq`.

With the older 1.5 release of `jq`, you may use

```bash
jq --argjson skipLibCheck true '.compilerOptions = { skipLibCheck: $skipLibCheck } + .compilerOptions' file
```

Use `--arg` instead of `--argjson` if you want the value to be the string `true` rather than the special boolean value `true`.

The following gives an alternative way of adding the key at the *end* (to what's mentioned in the other answer), which follows the same pattern as the above command. Note that I'm also switching to using `--arg` here to insert `true` as a string, just to show how that looks.

```bash
jq --arg skipLibCheck true '.compilerOptions += $ARGS.named' file
```

... which would give you

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "jerry": "Was a race car driver",
    "skipLibCheck": "true"
  }
}
```

With the older 1.5 release of `jq`, you may use

```bash
jq --arg skipLibCheck true '.compilerOptions += { skipLibCheck: $skipLibCheck }' file
```

Comment: @CaTx
I saw your comment about `$ARGS` not being recognised in `jq` release 1.5.  Note that release 1.6 has been available since the beginning of November 2018 and that this newer version, as well as supporting `$ARGS`, has several other enhancements and fixes.  If at all possible, you should update to a newer release of `jq`.  The tool is available as a static binary for Linux at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Thank you so much, @Kusalananda!  After switching to `jq` 1.6, your code works.  What should the syntax be it it were `jq` 1.5?

Comment: @CaTx See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you!  `jq` 1.6 surely is much more intuitive.  They should use this version for the package repo.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
$ jq '.compilerOptions.skipLibCheck=true' file.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```